# Android Studio : Unable to locate apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am trying to create an unsigned apk that I can share internally for testing. On Android Studio, I did the following :

1. Click Build -> Clean Project
2. Build -> Make Project

The build was successful with the following message :

> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. :app:preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE :volley:compileLint
>   :volley:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE :volley:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :volley:preReleaseBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:checkReleaseManifest
>   :volley:prepareReleaseDependencies :volley:compileReleaseAidl
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE :volley:mergeReleaseAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE :volley:compileReleaseNdk
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :volley:bundleRelease
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareBluetoothGattVolleyUnspecifiedLibrary
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2301Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugSources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugAndroidTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE :volley:preDebugBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:checkDebugManifest :volley:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :volley:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE :volley:compileDebugRenderscript
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :volley:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :volley:processDebugManifest
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>   :volley:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE :volley:copyDebugLint
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE :volley:packageDebugJar
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE :volley:packageDebugLocalJar
>   UP-TO-DATE :volley:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE :volley:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:processDebugAndroidTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :volley:compileDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 3.739 secs

However, I am unable to locate the apk. I tried looking in the app/outputs directory of my project, but that directory has just one folder called logs/ and no other folder. Any suggestions would help.

Comment: You should actually run application for creating debug build

Comment: There should not be an `app/outputs/` directory,  unless you made it yourself. `app/build/outputs/apk/` will be where the APK goes when you build it. However, neither of your steps will generate an APK. Android Studio does not seem to create an APK, through normal IDE operations, unless you run the project. There should be a Gradle task specifically for creating an unsigned APK (though I don't recall what it is off the top of my head).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make project does not make an unsigned apk. I have made the same mistake What you can do is build the unsigned apk using gradle. Just follow the following steps (you can do it faster than it took me to type the steps):

1. To the left of the run button you should see a drop down list saying "app" with an android logo to the left of it. click it.
2. click on "Edit Configurations"
3. Click the green plus button on top left and select "Gradle"
4. Where it says name, enter what ever you want but leave the rest blank. I set mine as "Assemble"
5. Below where it says "Before launch: Gradle task" click the green plus sign and select "Run Gradle Task"
6. Where it says "tasks" type in "assemble"
7. Press okay and okay to save it
8. Press the run button. the apk will appear in YourProjectFolderName>app>build>outputs>apk

to change the run button back to running your app via adb just click the drop down button from step 1 again and select "app"

Also note that you cannot install a unsigned APK on a physical device. whether you're emailing the apk, copying it to the phone storage over usb, or any other method it will NOT let you install it. You will either need to create a signed apk (its very simple) or connect each test device to your computer and install it through adb.